# Apply external function to Spark dataframe instead of RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe that looks as following:

```
> init_df
+----+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| id |                            var_1|                               var_2|
+----+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|   1| france, poland, usa, ukraine, ..| paris, warsaw, washington, kyiv, ..|
|   2|   germany, greece, lithuania, ..|         berlin, athens, vilnius, ..|
+----+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

I want to apply `KeyBERT()` keywords extraction model to each row of my `init_df`. I know how to apply external function/model using rdd:

```
# transform df to rdd  
my_rdd = init_df.rdd

# define the model
kw_model = KeyBERT()

# apply model to var_1 variable
final_rdd = my_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], kw_model.extract_keywords(x[1])))
```

But how to do the same using initial dataframe instead of rdd?
Also, is it possible to apply the model not only to the `var_1` variable, but to the `var_1` and `var_2` columns at once?